# How to check if a user has at least one Permission in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to display to end user that they have no permission assigned.

How can I do that with Django templates?

Answer (score 1):

> The currently logged-in user’s permissions are stored in the template
> variable **`{{ perms }}`**, read more **[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions)**

To check if the logged-in user has any permissions in the `foo` app, simply use:

```
{% if perms.foo %}
```

Requirements:

`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` context processor enabled

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a simple `if not` checking for permission groups.

```
{% if not user.groups.count %}
    Hey User, you do not have permissions.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Nice but this worked out for me well

{% not perms.count %}
    display message
{% endif %}

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for permissions in templates, the following code will suffice:

```
{% if perms.app_label.can_do_something %}
<form here>
{% endif %}
```

The currently logged-in user’s permissions are stored in the template variable `{{ perms }}`. This is an instance of `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper`, which is a template-friendly proxy of permissions.

More info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me well

```
{% not perms.count %}
    display message
{% endif %}
```